# Issues converting certain TIF compressions to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp to convert & stitch single-page TIF files to multi-page PDF file. The single-page TIF files are of different bit depths and compressions.

Here is the code-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> TIFfiles = new List<string>();
    Document document;
    PdfWriter pdfwriter;
    Bitmap tifFile;
    pdfFilename = <file path>.PDF;
    TIFfiles = <load the path to each TIF file in this array>;

    //Create document 
    document = new Document();

    // creation of the different writers
    pdfwriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new System.IO.FileStream(pdfFilename, FileMode.Create));

    document.Open();
    document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    foreach (string file in TIFfiles)
    {

        //load the tiff image  
        tifFile = new Bitmap(file);

        //Total number of pages

        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(tifFile.Width, tifFile.Height);
        document.SetPageSize(pgSize);
        document.NewPage();

        PdfContentByte cb = pdfwriter.DirectContent;

        tifFile.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, 0);
        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(tifFile, ImageFormat.Tiff);

        // scale the image to fit in the page
        img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        cb.AddImage(img);

    }

    document.Close();
}
```

This code works well and stitches & converts tifs to PDF. Issue is with processing time and pdf file size that it creates when processing certain types of TIFs.

For e.g.

Original TIF --> B&W/Bit depth 1/Compression CCITT T.6 --> Faster processing, PDF file size is ~1.1x times the TIF file size.

Original TIF --> Color/Bit depth 8/Compression LZW --> Faster processing, PDF file size is ~1.1x times the TIF file size.

Original TIF --> Color/Bit depth 24/Compression JPEG--> **Slow** processing, PDF file size is **~12.5x times** the TIF file size.

Why doesn't converting Color/Bit depth 24/Compression JPEG files gives similar result as other tif files?

Moreover, this issue is only with iTextSharp. I had a colleague test the same set of TIF samples using Java-iText and the resulting PDF was of smaller size (1.1x times) and had faster processing.

Unfortunately, I need to use .Net for this TIF to PDF conversion, so am stuck with using iTextSharp.
Any ideas/suggestions on how to get those Compression JPEG TIF files to create smaller size PDFs as it does for other TIF compressions?

Appreciate your help!

Regards,
AG

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using. WIth every new version, we've added support for more TIFF versions.

Comment: I am using v5.5.4.0. If there is an newer version than this, let me know. I can test with that version as well.

Comment: 5.5.5.0 is the latest, but 5.5.4.0 is recent enough for the TIFF updates. Maybe this is something that should be posted to the iText support team as there shouldn't be any substantial difference between iTextSharp and iText. Where can they contact you to get a sample TIFF file that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I have added my email address to my StackOverflow profile. Please request iText support team to reach me there for sample files. Appreciate your help! Thanks again!

Comment: Your request received the ticket number DEV-1364. It currently has the lowest priority since I do not know if your employer/customer is an iText Software customer. If he's already using iText in production, he probably is, because using iText 5.5.4 or iTextSharp 5.5.4.0 in a commercial context requires a commercial license.

Comment: As of now I am just evaluating whether iTextSharp meet our needs for TIFF to PDF conversion. It's only on DEV machine for a PoC. Any ETA on the ticket resolution?

Comment: Hi Bruno - Any updates on this?

Comment: It's in this week's sprint. (If you don't know what a sprint is, please catch up on Agile development.)

Comment: Hi Bruno - Any updates from the sprint?

Comment: Please ask the person who mailed you for the TIFF. I'm currently in a board meeting.

Comment: ok, just emailed him. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with the code you supplied, but found that the problem went away once I used Image.GetInstance instead of the bitmap used in your sample.  When using the code below, the file size and run time was the same between Java and C#.  If you have any questions about the sample, don't hesitate to ask.

```
        List<string> TIFfiles = new List<string>();
        Document document;
        PdfWriter pdfwriter;
        iTextSharp.text.Image tifFile;
        String pdfFilename = pdfFile;
        TIFfiles = new List<string>();
        TIFfiles.Add(tifFile1);
        TIFfiles.Add(tifFile2);
        TIFfiles.Add(tifFile3);
        TIFfiles.Add(tifFile4);
        TIFfiles.Add(tifFile5);
        TIFfiles.Add(tifFile6);
        TIFfiles.Add(tifFile7);

        //Create document 
        document = new Document();

        // creation of the different writers
        pdfwriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new System.IO.FileStream(pdfFilename, FileMode.Create));

        document.Open();
        document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 50)
        {
            foreach (string file in TIFfiles)
            {

                //load the tiff image  
                tifFile = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(file);

                //Total number of pages

                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(tifFile.Width, tifFile.Height);
                document.SetPageSize(pgSize);
                document.NewPage();

                PdfContentByte cb = pdfwriter.DirectContent;

                // scale the image to fit in the page
                tifFile.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                cb.AddImage(tifFile);

            }
            i++;
        }
        document.Close();
```

Comment: Excellent! I made the changes you suggested and it works for me as well. Thanks a ton!